# How do I capture and store the outgoing HTTP requests sent from my server?

Tags: linux, http, middleware, webhooks, sniffing

I have Ruby application running on EC2 instance. The application send HTTP requests to several web services (SOAP, REST, .. etc).

I would like to store all outgoing http requests from that application into Mongodb collection.

I am looking for an out of box solution like a tool or self hosted service that i can install into my Linux server to capture all outgoing HTTP requests and store it or send it to a web hook.

Also I would like to know what is the best practice to follow in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `tshark` utility to capture traffic and use appropriate filters to for filtering traffic and formatting output.

Example:

```
tshark -i eth0 -s 0 -R 'http' -T text  host 192.168.123.3
```

Output: https://pastebin.com/raw/rGaaPUrz